Flutter Generate TreeView From json data
I have a table with three columns (parentID, childID, treeName).
I would like to generate a tree view from json data.
What I have tried?
There are a lot of example for hardcoded tree view, but non for dynamically generated.
I have tried graphview, but it needs a lot of screen space to display.
what I am looking is a simple tree view as follows


The tree view image in the question is taken from flutter_fancy_tree_view package on pub.dev 
The package allows you to dynamically create and manipulate tree views.
Also you can check the following gallery on fluttergems.dev for other tree view packages.
